# if you would have told me to move I would have moved

Tags: descriptive-grammar

I was standing I gave this answer this answer . is this a correct way

Comment: "If you _had told_ me to move I would have moved." is the usual construction.

Comment: It's an American usage, but many UK speakers find it odd.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's grammatically correct, and you used the proper tense.

The lack of any contractions ("If you would've", "If you'd have...", etc.) makes it feel a bit stiff to me, but not using them isn't wrong, so don't worry.

Comment: Actually, "If you  _would have_..." is not quite the usual usage.

Comment: Usual for whom?

Comment: ....usual for just about anyone who knows how to use _whom_.

Comment: @Cascabel - So usual for only a relatively small fraction of the population?